# unusual debugging in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a simple loop code, and try to debug it. Imagine there is 100 step in my code(a counter cont it). is it possible in VS2010 that for example I trace step 1 and 2 and then ignore the rest until 90,again start debugging from 90 to 100?

I know that I can use an if condition in my code, but can VS 2010 handle such this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

press right click near  the breakpoint 
you will see

hit count...

condition...

etc.

you can use this to control the break point